# Interpretation of Random Forest Classifier Output

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest, text-classification, confusion-matrix

I am doing a text classification using RandomForestClassifier, I am a little bit confused about the results. After using vectorize my text using doc2vec, I combined it with some numerical features to predict my class (Class 0, 1 and 2). My data is split 75% training and 25% test. **After running my model I have a poor accuracy but a perfect confusion matrix...
May you shade lights?**

```python
np.random.seed(7)
def train_RFC_grid(X,y):
    n_estimators = [800]
    min_samples_split = [7]
    min_samples_leaf = [1]
    max_depth = [None]
    bootstrap = [True]
    oob_score = [True]
    random_state = [1]
    #max_features = [None]

    parameters = {'n_estimators': n_estimators, 'min_samples_leaf': 
                  min_samples_leaf,'min_samples_split': min_samples_split, 
                  'bootstrap': bootstrap,'max_depth': max_depth, 
                  'oob_score': oob_score,'random_state':random_state}

    clf = GridSearchCV(RFC(verbose=0,n_jobs=-1), cv=10, 
                        param_grid=parameters,scoring = 'accuracy')
    clf.fit(X, y)
    return clf
```

Below is my train model

```python
RFC_grid_clf = train_RFC_grid(X_Wbody_train,y_train)
```

After training, I obtain 0.51 accuracy.

```python
print (RFC_grid_clf.best_score_, ": Best Accuracy score on Cross Validation Sets") : 0.5108518518518519 : Best Accuracy score on Cross Validation Sets
```

On the test, I obtain 0.50 accuracy.

```python
print (RFC_grid_clf.score(X_Wbody_test,y_test)) 0.506555555556 Validation Sets
```

BUT my confusion matrix looks like this:

```python
array([[3033,    0,    0],
      [   0, 2957,    0],
      [   0,    0, 3010]])
```

AND my classification report:

```python
          precision    recall  f1-score   support

Class 0       1.00      1.00      1.00      3033
Class 1       1.00      1.00      1.00      2957
Class 2       1.00      1.00      1.00      3010
avg/ttl       1.00      1.00      1.00      9000
```

**I cannot understand why I have a poor accuracy but a perfect confusion matrix...
May you shade lights?**